# How to create load tests with jmeter when our website has no authorization with create user ... but it has authorization via social networks

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

How to create load tests with jmeter when our website has no authorization with create user ...  but it has authorization via social networks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the majority of cases authorization via social networks is being done using [OAuth protocol](https://oauth.net/2/), the implementation differs depending on social network, i.e.:

- [Facebook: Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)
- [Twitter: Authentication](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth)
- etc.

So basically your test needs to contain [Authorization: Bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-6.1.1) token (you can add it using [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)).

If you're lucky enough your application may rely on "permanent" tokens or tokens living long enough so you could complete your testing. Otherwise you will have to obtain tokens somehow and even refresh them if they expire prior to your test end i.e. in case of [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing)

You can find generic guidance steps in the [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article.